# Quickbooks SDK - Entering Timesheet Data

Tags: c#, quickbooks

My (potential) client downloads a csv list of hours for employees from our state's social services department.

I will be opening and processing the csv file, and then (hopefully) using the SDK to enter timesheet data for the week.

I've searched the QBSDK_ProGuide and I don't see what I need.

Can anybody point me in the right direction for entering data into timesheets via the SDK?

Thank You!

*** I just found TimeTrackAdd which seems to be what I need. Anyone got experience using it?

Answer (score 0):

Got my 'proof of concept' done. Just in case someone else gets stuck, here's the link to Intuit's onscreen reference:

https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

The only tough part is knowing what to look for :)